# How many synapses when weights are shared?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

The question concerns the following diagram over a very simple CNN:

[image]

L0 is the input layer with 3 inputs and a filter lying on top of the two top most inputs, L1 is a convolutional layer with 2 neurons representing each possible filter location (top 2 or bottom 2, no padding). There are 2 weights (the gray boxes) and they are shared between the 2 filter locations. 2 signals can be received by the weights at any time and they are propagated toward the neuron that represents the filter location (red lines).

In correct terminology, do we say that we have 2 synapses here, or 4 (or 2 pairs)? It looks like there are 4, but the weights between them are shared hence the confusion. Thank you!